# Kubernetes: LoadBalancer keeps pending even - in intro video it works

Tags: kubernetes, docker-for-mac

Update: Ok I am not alone: https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/2445

Following [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/examples.git), he gets an External-ip:

I got the YAML files from GitHub.

```
wordpress         LoadBalancer   10.108.161.250   <pending>     80:30806/TCP
```

Why are my LoadBalancer just pending when his(in the video) is not?

And please note that he do has a LoadBalencer that expose an external ip for the service.

Comment: Where is your kubernetes cluster deployed?

Comment: On My mac - it is the Docker for Mac that includes Kubernetes orchestrations.

Comment: Looking at the github readme I can't find anything mac-specific

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed in 18.03.0-ce-rc1-mac54:

From release notes:

  `` - Kubernetes Load balanced services are no longer marked as `Pending`. ``

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't seem to be fixed. I'm still getting this regularly.

Answer (score 3):

The `LoadBalancer` services require support from the underlying infrastructure. They work automatically if you deploy them in supported providers such as AWS or GKE.

They doesn't work if you deploy them locally on your Mac or with minikube

Details here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/create-external-load-balancer/#external-load-balancer-providers

Comment: But the guy is presenting this as Docker for Mac?

Comment: When you select LoadBalancer as the service type, it's an instruction to spin up a separate machine to act as a gateway exposing your service. On minikube that would be the equivalent of spinning up another VM separate from the one running your cluster. Nobody bothered to implement that since minikube is meant for development

Answer (score 2):

Docker for Mac makes the LoadBalancers available at `http://localhost:{port}` automagically.

Comment: Thanks, In what version?

Comment: @ChrisG. I'm on edge personally  -- Version 18.02.0-ce-mac53 (22617) as of today.

Comment: I am pretty new to kubernetes, I do not know what {port} will be. How would I access the pod external from a browser?

NAMESPACE       NAME                   TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
microservices   api-gateway-service    LoadBalancer   10.98.94.95     <pending>     3000:32724/TCP   5m

Comment: Not anymore. The v2.4.0.0 version shows the external IP now as `pending` instead of `localhost`. https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/4903